# Principal value integral $\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

I wish to compute Cauchy principal value integral 
$$P\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx$$
numerically, but using the PV prescription 
$$P\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(x+i \epsilon)^2}+\frac{1}{(x-i\epsilon)^2})$$
could introduce extra imaginary part into the integral while I want it to remain real.

I also tried 
$$P\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx=\int_0^{y-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx+\int_{y+\epsilon}^1\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx-\frac{2}{\epsilon}f(y)$$
which gives relatively good result but numerically it's large minus large so I have to keep the intergration really accurate, and that's hard for me.

Another way I read in some papers is 
$$P\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)f'(y)-\dots}{(x-y)^2}dx$$ but I can't produce the same result with the former one using this method, I don't know where I did wrong.

Does anyone know any good PV prescription in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The prescription to use (and works in all cases) is the definition $$P\int_{0}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[\int_{0}^{y-\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx +\int_{ y+\epsilon}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2}dx\right],$$
i.e., the singularity at $x=y$ is approached symmetrically from both sides.

In you case, the principal value is divergent unless $f(y) =0$.

Comment: But I wish to cut more of that singularity and obtain the same result with the $\frac{2}{\epsilon}$ one, so in this case your method only applies for $\frac{1}{x-y}$.

Comment: @Turgon: I am not sure I understand your comment. My answer is simply stating _the definition_ of the Cauchy-principal value. If you are interested in a principal value that is defined differently then please state so in your question.